# Is there an optimal configuration or any way in which I can effectively connect

Tags: batteries, series, speed

I currently have a 72V e-bike.

The configuration of the batteries directly from manufacturer is 6 12v 20AH valve regulated lead acid batteries connected in series. In taking the  limiter harness out of the mix my speed went up roughly 15kmh (this is being done strictly as a learning expierience and only driven on my own private property.) I have a 12V 14 Ah lead acid and another 12V 6.5Ah lead acid. I was wondering if connecting the two 14Ah and 6.5 Ah in a parallel circuit and then adding to overall power bank in series thus having 96V.  Will my speed increase any more? Is this an idea worth pursuing and if my configuration won't work is there any other that is worth pursuing?

Alternatively I'm taking one 12V to power an amplifier on bike.

Comment: More likely the resulting speed will be 0 after the speed controller is destroyed.

Comment: in the sine wave controller i currently have it should be alright but in regards to the batteries is this an option in how i describe installing?

Comment: If you connect them in series : congratulations; you have lost 2/3 of the range thanks to the 6.5 Ah one. If you connect them in parallel : ok that's 20Ah, but you're only boosting  72 to 84V. Barely worthwhile even if teh controller can take it.

Comment: thank you. This is all new to me and messing around while doing so with my sons ability to marvel at what Dad did(even if its marginally better and with the real help coming from here) keeps me and my kids doing something other than minecraft. lol

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'll be *that guy*.

tl; dr version: want to go fast? Forget hopping-up your e-bike. Get trained and licensed for a motorcycle, then go get one, electric or otherwise. You will be happier and live longer.

Now, what will be your speed result if you add the batteries? If you overcook the bike's chassis / brakes and plant yourself into a tree... zero. Assuming you don't fry the controller first, as [Brian Drummond](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/16324/brian-drummond) commented.

What's the problem? That setup of yours with its passel of lead-acid batteries is *heavy*, and has lots of kinetic energy when moving at speed. Not a good combination for an e-bike to begin with, and by adding even *more* weight and *more* speed you're just making a bad situation even worse.

In all seriousness, if going fast *in an off-road setting* and *not on multi-use trails* is your goal, consider something that is built to do that, like the Sur-Ron electric dirt bike (also marketed by Segway.) More here: https://lunacycle.com/sur-ron-x-bike-black-edition/

Even better: https://www.ktm.com/us/e-ride/

Do *not* consider something like this, which is an accident waiting to happen (and an approximation of what you're intending to build): https://www.onyxmotorbikes.com/products/rcr-72v. California DMV is currently investigating these guys for violating the e-bike classification.

In general, e-bikes have proven themselves to be a hazard *especially for older men*, even when they obey their e-bike classification rules. Why? They encourage less-fit and less-skilled riders to use them, and ride them at higher speeds than they could without the e-assist. More about that here: https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/apr/25/older-men-using-e-bikes-behind-rising-death-toll-among-dutch-cyclists

Comment: I am currently asingle father of two boys and being a pipefitter just falls short of balancing  the books once the insurance payments get tallied in. Would love a bike that hey goes on the highway, but i moved within 10 km of the mill in which i work so that insurance dose'nt surpass birthday presents. Turns out that i make just too much for gst and w.e other handouts gov gives but just not enough to be where i'd like. Thanks for your kind insight duly noted.

Comment: That's the struggle. Field experience with e-bikes has led to rulemaking, establishing a compromise between the utility of e-bikes and safety of the user and public. As things stand, highway-legal but license- (and insurance-) free e-bikes have to abide by certain limits (28mph in California for Class 1 and 2, 30mph for Class 3; EU rules are similar).

Comment: E-bikes are still new, and their social contract is still being worked out. Even with the limits we have in California, practically every walk I take on a mixed-use path I feel like some jackhole on a 75lb+ e-bike is going to plow into me or my partner. California already limits e-bike use in parks (banned on trails) and on dedicated bike paths (class 1 or 2 only), but that still doesn't seem enough.

Comment: I do appreciate the concern and when I was the guy driving i an truly say i'd never think id be riding an ebike just for the douchy factor some ahole riders have. lol

Comment: E-bike hack culture is a thing. It's such a common ask about how to defeat the limiters, which is really just firmware in many cases. Where I live we also have motorized bicycle hack culture using China-sourced 2-strokes, fitted with expansion chambers and other go-faster stuff. I kinda like the idea, being a dirt biker from way back. However, these contraptions manage up to 45mph in some cases, on a spindly cruiser bike frame with sketchy brakes and no suspension. Not good.